# Need a way to place a <ScrollView/> over an <Image/> in Xamarin layout XAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-relativelayout

I have the need for a scrollview on top of a background image. I found a number of recommendations to use a , making the image the first element. What I end up with is:

```xml
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout Padding="0">
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="Background" />
            <ScrollView>
                <!-- Various components -->
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Using the above, I get a screen that looks correct, but the ScrollView doesn't scroll.

Am I missing something? Or does anyone have an alternative to the layout above? The background needs to be fixed and not scroll with the other elements on "top" of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a way to do this such that the two main requirements (fixed background, scrollable elements) are met.

Instead of using RelativeLayout, use a Grid. The following layout works as needed...

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- Use a Grid, rather than a RelativeLayout -->
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="Background" />
            <ScrollView>
                <!-- Various components -->
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You could mark yourself as a solution,it may help others.